# this.state is giving null after api call

Tags: reactjs

I am consoling state right after my function call in componentDidMount but it's giving data as EMPTY String.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: ""
    };
  }

  getData = () => {
    functionApiCall().then(res => {
      this.setState({
        data: res.data
      }); // Here the state is getting set
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    console.log(this.state.data); //Empty string
  }

  render() {
    return <></>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Your api is returning null

Comment: Did you checked at API end?

Comment: Sohan did you check my answer? Please give some feedback whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the api call is returning null , maybe change it like this

```
  getData = () => {
      functionApiCall().then(res => {
      if(res && res.data) {
      this.setState({
        data: res.data
      })// Here the state is getting set
     } 
    }
  }
```

Above should be fine, but just in case try this

```
 getData = () => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          functionApiCall().then(res => {
          if(res && res.data) {
          this.setState({
            data: res.data
          }, () => { resolve(res.data) })// Here the state is getting set
         } 
        } });
      }
```

And componentDidMount wait for your promise which resolves after state is set

```
 async componentDidMount(){
        await this.getData();
        console.log(this.state.data) //NULL
      }
```

Comment: As I mentioned, the API is successfully returning the data but I am not getting the state value right after the API's function is getting called in DidMount.

Comment: I guess return a promise on getData() and wait for promise to resolve in componentDidMount

Comment: I am quite sure that is the same thing you're saying. Promise is getting resolved.

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous so you cannot immediately access it.

You can render conditionally like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  getData = () => {
    functionApiCall().then(res => {
      this.setState({
        data: res.data
      });
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>Data: {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}</div>;
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Sample [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-fire-p7538) with a fake api

Comment: If this was the reason value of data wouldn't have changed to null from ''.

Comment: @kooskoos he is using promise .then in an entirely different codeblock, where the console.log is it is not aware of the promise and will continue to execute.

Comment: @kooskoos Yea, that's a bit weird. The original state is an empty string, not null. Good point.

Comment: This code also works even the data is empty string like this   this.state = {data: ''}